# Поиск пути A star python

Tags: python, поиск-пути

Пытаюсь написать алгоритм для поиска пути с помощью Python, но он почему-то не определяет кратчайший путь(часто идет напрямую), а когда невозможно найти путь, то просто надолго зацикливается. Уже несколько дней бьюсь над этой проблемой, но решения так и не нашел

```py
def heuristic(a, b):
    # Манхэттенское расстояние между точками a и b
    return abs(b.position[0] - a.position[0]) + abs(b.position[1] - a.position[1])


def find_path(cells: MapController, start_cell: Cell, end_cell: Cell, disabled_cells_types: list[CellType] = None) \
        -> list[Cell] | None:
    if disabled_cells_types is None:
        disabled_cells_types = []

    open_list = []
    closed_list = set()
    path = []

    g_score = {start_cell.cell_id: 0}
    open_list.append((start_cell, heuristic(start_cell, end_cell)))

    came_from = {}

    while open_list:
        current_cell, f_score = min(open_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
        open_list.remove((current_cell, f_score))

        if current_cell == end_cell:
            # Путь найден, восстанавливаем его
            path.append(end_cell)
            while current_cell.cell_id in came_from:
                current_cell = came_from[current_cell.cell_id]
                path.insert(0, current_cell)
            return path  # Возвращаем найденный путь

        closed_list.add(current_cell.cell_id)

        for dx, dy in [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]:
            neighbor = cells.get_cell(cell_id=current_cell.cell_id + dx + 10 * dy)
            if neighbor is None or neighbor.cell_type in disabled_cells_types or neighbor.cell_id in closed_list:
                continue

            tentative_g_score = g_score[current_cell.cell_id] + neighbor.move_time

            if neighbor not in open_list or tentative_g_score < g_score.get(neighbor.cell_id, float('inf')):
                g_score[neighbor.cell_id] = tentative_g_score
                f_score = tentative_g_score + heuristic(neighbor, end_cell)
                open_list.append((neighbor, f_score))
                came_from[neighbor.cell_id] = current_cell

    # Если open_list пуст, значит, путь невозможно найти
    return None
```

Карта состоит из квадратных клеток, которые являются датаклассами

```py
class CellType(Enum):
    GRASS = 'grass'
    FOREST = 'forest'
    FOOTHILLS = 'foothills'
    HILLS = 'hills'
    HIGH_HILLS = 'high_hills'
    WATER = 'water'
    TOWN = 'town'


@dataclass
class Cell:
    cell_id: int
    resources: dict[str, int]
    move_time: int
    cell_type: CellType
    x: int
    y: int
    parameters: dict
    color: None | str = None
```

код функции для получения клеток

```py
    def get_cell(self, cell_id: int = None) -> Cell | None:

        cell = None

        if cell_id is not None:
            cell = self.cells_by_id.get(cell_id, None)

        return cell
```

Все  функции для получения клеток соседей корректно работают, скорее всего есть проблема в определении счета для клеток соседей из-за добавления нового атрибута время движения